# Glide is not loading gif url in android 4.4.4 and below

Tags: android, android-glide, android-4.4-kitkat

i'm trying to load the GIF url in my app using Glide. the code works fine from android 5.0 to 9.0. but same code is not working for android 4.4.4 and below. the url never load , here is the Log

```
05-11 21:08:16.819 6245-6245/com.pikasapps.carswallpapershd W/Glide: Load failed for https://my-android-apps.com/wallpapers/fotos/upload/category/motivacion.jpg with size [516x341]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException(failed to connect to my-android-apps.com/2a01:238:20a:202:1091:: (port 443) after 2500ms)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException(failed to connect to my-android-apps.com/2a01:238:20a:202:1091:: (port 443) after 2500ms)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to my-android-apps.com/2a01:238:20a:202:1091:: (port 443) after 2500ms
```